# BufferedReader readLine not reaching end of stream using HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, bufferedreader

I am trying to download the html from a website and I have tried two different ways.  Each time the InputStreamReader or BufferReader stops in the same place and I cannot figure out why.

IDE: Android Studio using API 28

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String html;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    html = getTheHtml("http://www.posh24.se/kandisar");

    Log.i("html: ", "" + html);
    Log.i("Length", "" + html.length());
}

public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        // String result = null;
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        StringBuilder response = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

            if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader((new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream())));
                response = new StringBuilder();

                String inputLine;

                while((inputLine = br.readLine())!= null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                    response.append("\n");
                }
                br.close();
            }
            return response.toString();
//                InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
//                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
//                int data = reader.read();
//
//                while(data != -1){
//                    char current = (char) data;
//                    result += current;
//                    data = reader.read();
//                }
//                return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Failed";
        }
    }
}

public String getTheHtml (String url){
    String result = null;
    DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
    try {
        result = task.execute(url).get();
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Failed";
    }
}
}
```

Here is my Logcat starting two lines before the end of the stream where it suddenly stopped:

```
<div class="title">Lista:</div>
        <div class
06-14 01:02:20.745 10602-10602/com.example.heato.guessthatcelebrity I/Length: 55847
06-14 01:02:20.769 10602-10602/com.example.heato.guessthatcelebrity D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
06-14 01:02:20.843 10602-10629/com.example.heato.guessthatcelebrity I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
06-14 01:02:20.844 10602-10629/com.example.heato.guessthatcelebrity I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
06-14 01:02:20.844 10602-10629/com.example.heato.guessthatcelebrity I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-14 01:02:20.844 10602-10629/com.example.heato.guessthatcelebrity D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
06-14 01:02:20.844 10602-10629/com.example.heato.guessthatcelebrity W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
06-14 01:02:20.844 10602-10629/com.example.heato.guessthatcelebrity D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
06-14 01:02:20.853 10602-10629/com.example.heato.guessthatcelebrity D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xeadc0920: maj 3 min 1 rcv 4
06-14 01:02:20.890 10602-10629/com.example.heato.guessthatcelebrity D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xeadc0920: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe3695500)
06-14 01:02:20.891 10602-10629/com.example.heato.guessthatcelebrity E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
06-14 01:02:20.972 10602-10629/com.example.heato.guessthatcelebrity D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xeadc0920: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe3695500)
```

I have googled and googled till my googler is sore... Any help would be much appreciated. Yes, this is a tutorial that I'm trying to follow, and I'm trying my best not to let my anxiety and insecurity about seemingly inexplicable errors keep me from learning how to program!!

Comment: You never set a request method.  The default would be GET.  Is the endpoint you are trying to hit a GET or POST endpoint?

Comment: Also, have you tried _debugging_ your app code?  If there is an exception, the stack trace from that would probably be helpful here.

Comment: You aren't logging the lines as you read them, so the only way the `<div>`s can possibly get logged is after the read loop exits, which means you *do* reach end of stream. Please clarify.

Comment: ran your code in doInBackground with the url listed. it worked for me. I just had to wrap InputStream in a GzipInputstream as the content encoding was gzip.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I really appreciate it.   It turned out that the buffered reader was capturing the entire html of the web page, but printing it to logcat threw me off because it truncated the message and made it seem like it had just stopped well short of the full stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the length of the logcat message is limited, and a too long message will be truncated. Check the limit with `adb logcat -g`:

```
$ adb logcat -g
main: ring buffer is 256Kb (254Kb consumed), max entry is 5120b, max payload is 4068b
system: ring buffer is 256Kb (242Kb consumed), max entry is 5120b, max payload is 4068b
crash: ring buffer is 256Kb (3Kb consumed), max entry is 5120b, max payload is 4068b
```

In your case, seems the length of your html string (`Log.i("Length", "" + html.length());`) is correct, so the problem is just about logcat's output, you can check the full string by saving the string into a file, or split the string into small slices.

Comment: Thank you very much! I went ahead and performed the function I wanted as if the stream had completed and it worked.  It just truncated the full string because it was so long.

Answer (score 0):

Try logging the exceptions:

```
Log.e(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "Request failed", e);
```

The output from `printStackTrace` is not being captured anywhere.

Comment: This is helpful information, but it might work better as a comment, since it is not a direct answer.

Answer (score 0):

> result = task.execute(url).get();

Pretty bad to use the .get() statement.

Remove it.

Your result will be available in onPostExecute() so handle the result there.